# How to get artist, album, or track metrics from Spotify API, if possible

Tags: spotify

I have been looking into the [Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/) over the last few days, and it's not clear to me whether any of the following information is available:

- For artists, either their stream counts or album sales or any other metrics that indicate how popular an artist is.
- Same for albums and tracks, any indication of popularity of the album or track

Here's output from their /get-artist endpoint for Kanye West:

[image]

We only receive a `followers` count of 16011935, which I assume is their Spotify followers, and a `popularity` of 95 that appears to be on a 0 - 100 scale and is presumably derived from the `followers` metric. As far as metrics for albums are concerned, from their /get-album endpoint:

[image]

Here we receive a `popularity` for Kanye's Donda album, but no other metrics associated with the album. And from their /get-track endpoint, there are no metrics at all associated with the track.

Am I missing something? Going into this, I sort of assumed that the Spotify web API would have some additional metrics on artists, albums, and tracks, but perhaps not?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you're correct in your analysis, as in Spotify APIs do not directly give access to any kind of streaming metrics. Also note that the popularity is a dynamic metric which changes over time, not only related to follower counts. An alternative way to get some kind of streaming info would be to look at external data sources, such as [last.fm](https://www.last.fm/api), but of course this requires you to match the two APIs.